# Backbone.js single view jquery slide with history

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view that uses an existing div as an element. Div is being used as a horizontal slider with next and pev buttons...

```
<div id='wrapperHomeScreen'> 
    <div id='wrapperHomeSlides'>
        <div id='slideHomeScreen1' class='slideHomeScreen'  >
             <div> </div>
        </div>
        <div id='slideHomeScreen2' class='slideHomeScreen'>
             <div> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href='#tab0' id='btnMainPrev' class='btnScreenDir'></a>
    <a href='#tab1' id='btnMainNext' class='btnScreenDir'></a>
</div>
```

In backbone view I am binding click event to the directions button, and in the event function I am using jquery to animate the slide. Now I need a way to use router with the direction buttons.

here is the view...

```
var HomeScreenView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el:'#wrapperHomeScreen', 

      initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(Backbone.history, 'route', this.onRouteChanged);
          },

      events: {
        'click .btnScreenDir': 'slide',
        'click .btnHomeSlide':'slide',

      },


        slide: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            target = $(event.target)
            var id = target.attr('id');
            var position = $('#wrapperHomeSlides').position();
            router.navigate( target.attr('href'), {trigger: true} );// navigate to url

                if (id == 'btnMainPrev'){
                    if(currentSlide != 0 ){

                        currentSlide -= 1;
                    }
                }else if(id=='btnMainNext'){
                    if(currentSlide != homeSlidesCount - 1 ){

                        currentSlide += 1;
                    }
                }

                newPos = -1 * currentSlide * slideWidth;

                $('#wrapperHomeSlides').animate({left: newPos}, 500);


        },
        onRouteChanged: function(e) { 

            //will i use this function?




        }
});
```

And the router:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "tab0": "showTab1",
        "tab1": "showTab2"
      },
      showTab1: function() {

      },
      showTab2: function() {

      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use router.navigate method:

```
router.navigate('tab1');
```

and

```
router.navigate('tab2');
```